# How to find files with duplicated content in given a directory? SHELL

Tags: shell, directory, find

I need to find files with the same (duplicated) content inside them in a given directory. And I need to use shell code.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Rather than comparing every pair of files, which will take O(n^2) time for n files, it's much faster to hash them all with e.g. md5sum.  You can sort the output of that, and all identical files will appear next to each other.

Comment: Please don't update the title to indicate that your problem has been resolved. Just accept an answer (which you've done).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this: BASH**

```
find -type f -exec md5sum '{}' ';' | sort | uniq --all-repeated=separate -w 33 | cut -c 35-
```

**Explanation**:

Find all files, calculate their MD5SUM, find duplicates by comparing the MD5SUM, print the names

Comment: Didn't know about `-w` or `--all-repeated` for `uniq`, thanks!

Comment: @DariusDarius If this is fine, mark it as resolved which would be more polite.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Read here... http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3555/find-duplicate-files-based-on-size-first-then-md5-hash